# Running unit tests on a Java sub-project in Android Studio

Tags: junit, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am not able to run any JUnit test on a Gradle sub-project in Android Studio. This project does not rely on Android in any way, it uses only the Java Gradle plugin.

The Android Gradle project has the following folder structure:

- settings.gradle
- app/build.gradle
- backend/build.gradle

*settings.gradle* lists the two sub-projects:

```
include ':app', ':backend'
```

The *app* folder contains an Android project. It's build.gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.6'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':backend')
}
```

The *backend* folder contains a normal Java Gradle project, which *app* depends on. It's build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}
```

The backend project has several unit tests located in *src/test/java/...* 
When I try to execute any of them, I get an error stating the Android Studio cannot find the test class:

```
Class not found: "com.test.DummyTest"
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Executing `gradle test` works as expected. Is there any configuration I have missed, or is it plain impossible to get the unit tests to work in Android Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for running JUnit test in Java modules was added in version 0.3.6 of Android Studio:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60916

Answer (score 0):

1- If you are using Android Studio,It sounds like [Gradle Unit Test Plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin) is what you are searching for.

2- As an alternative, you may use The EAP of IntelliJ IDEA 13, which includes all of the Android Studio features except for the redesigned new project wizard and the App Engine cloud endpoints integration, is available now

Comment: Gradle Unit Test Plugin is for running unit tests in a Android module, while I want to run unit test in a Java module.